# C# datagridview didnt show full data from text file after merge two text file together

Tags: c#

After i merge two text file together and i try to read the merged file in my datagridview, i do realize that my datagridview didnt show the full data of my text file.

here is my datagridview after i debug.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRzQB.jpg)

here is my text file format after merge.(i cant merge the file in sequence since i still new in coding)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l43Wo.jpg)

here is my code.

```
 private bool loadTxt()
    {
        // try locate the txt file, exist or not
        try
        {
            StreamReader rrr = new StreamReader("merge.txt");
            rrr.Close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // read all line from txt file
        var file = File.ReadAllLines("merge.txt");
        string DateTag = "<Date>";
        string NIDTag = "<News ID>";
        string StockIDTag = "<StockID>";
        string LatestPriceTag = "<Latest Price>";
        string TargetPriceTag = "<Target Price>";
        string StockComTag = "<StockCompany>";

        string Date = "";
        string NID = "";
        string StockID = "";
        string LatestPrice = "";
        string TargetPrice = "";
        string StockCom = "";

        int row = dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1;

        // Loop through the file and find targeted data to store in datagridview1
        for (int i = 0; i < file.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (file[i] == DateTag)
            {
                dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
                Date = file[i + 1];
                dataGridView2.Rows[row].Cells[0].Value = Date;
            }

            if (file[i] == NIDTag)
            {
                NID = file[i + 1];
                dataGridView2.Rows[row].Cells[1].Value = NID;
            }

            if (file[i] == StockIDTag)
            {
                StockID = file[i + 1];
                dataGridView2.Rows[row].Cells[2].Value = StockID;
            }

            if (file[i] == LatestPriceTag)
            {
                LatestPrice = file[i + 1];
                dataGridView2.Rows[row].Cells[3].Value = LatestPrice;
            }

            if (file[i] == TargetPriceTag)
            {
                TargetPrice = file[i + 1];
                dataGridView2.Rows[row].Cells[4].Value = TargetPrice;       
            }

            if (file[i] == StockComTag)
            {
                StockCom = file[i + 1];
                dataGridView2.Rows[row].Cells[5].Value = StockCom;
                row++;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think You are adding data to the same row

```
int row = dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1;  //your row
```

and using `row` for adding every value to `dataGridView2`

```
if (file[i] == DateTag)
            {
                dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
                Date = file[i + 1];
                dataGridView2.Rows[row].Cells[0].Value = Date; //same [row]
            }
```

hope it helps !!